# How to fix Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object?

Tags: php

I have a problem on line 26 it says: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C:\OpenServer\domains\bashlam.com\models\Product.php on line 26 i can not find the problem, i did var_dump on ($result) is says bool(false), so do not understand what i am doing wrong?

```
public static function getLatestProducts($count = self::SHOW_BY_DEFAULT, $page = 1)
{
    $count = intval($count);

    $db = Db::getConnection();

    $productList = array();

    $result = $db->query("SELECT id, name, price, image, is_new FROM product "
            . "WHERE status = '1' "
            . "ORDER BY id DESC "
            . "LIMIT " . $count);
    var_dump($result);   
    $i = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch()){
        $productList[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
        $productList[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
        $productList[$i]['image'] = $row['image'];
        $productList[$i]['price'] = $row['price'];
        $productList[$i]['is_new'] = $row['is_new'];
        $i++;
    }

    return $productList;
}
```

Comment: check if you are connected and if yes then your query is the problem

Comment: it's this one: while($row = $result->fetch())

Comment: I have that problem only when i run it on localhost otherwise it works.

Comment: Maybe be you cannot connect to database check your configuration.

Comment: my connection is ok, it is connected, i get this problem only when i run it on localhost, on my webserver it works greate, but i need to work on my localhost

Comment: So run your query on phpmyadmin and be sure it's OK.

Comment: The query works: SELECT id, name, price, is_new FROM product WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4

Comment: but still the same problem

Comment: how can i print_r the query string? when i say print_r($result) it doesn't show anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for PDO::query which says:

> PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure.

Your SQL Query made a mistake, so be sure it's right.

Comment: yes i had a image column in my qyuery string that i did not have in my table i removed it from query string and checked out in phpmyadmin and now the query string works great but i still says the same

Comment: Maybe status is int try WHERE status = 1 and remove ''

Comment: Yes it int a removed "" but is says still the same

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: i get error on line 26 but i do not sure if it is a query, when i copy the query and paste it in phpmyadmin it works

Comment: Do you copy "LIMIT " . $count too ?

Comment: instead of $count i set LIMIT = 1

Comment: Like this and it works: SELECT id, name, price, is_new FROM product WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: I am not sure that is OK but how can i check if it is ok?

Comment: where exactly should i set it`?

Comment: Replace $count with 1 as well as you query in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: I replaced it and now it is workin :-) Thank you very much, but why i can not use the $count?

Comment: What should i do to use the $count so?

Comment: What is self::SHOW_BY_DEFAULT?

Comment: const SHOW_BY_DEFAULT = 4;

Comment: Add echo $count; before query execution and check its value.

Comment: Sorry this is my 3rd time i use the stackoverflow.com would you plz explain men how i can vote up and where so i will do it without no problem

Comment: I says once you earn of total 15 reputation your votes will change the publicly displayed post score

Comment: Yes i use LIMIT 5 instead LIMIT . $count now it is working, but i do not understand why it isn't works with $count. I said echo $count and it shows men the number 5

Comment: Yes i did ecxactly the same now it works for me, thank you now i can work localy

Answer (score 0):

You have error in query so "$db->query()" return null or false. You can print your query and dubug it in mysql console.

Comment: where is the mysql console?

Comment: I suggest run it on phpmyadmin, but you can in linux or windows console.

Answer (score -1):

Statut is probably an int so just remove the ' '